# Angular4+webpack3 prod build getting error after hosting app in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

After successfully prod build with angualr4+webpack3 getting below error on 2nd refresh on browser, iam getting below error

`uncaught exception: reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators`

if i update index.html with below script

 `<script src="Reflect.js"></script>`

Its working fine
 but why i need to put this in index.html ? is it not rendered in webpack main.bundle.js?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a polyfill. I use core-js's polyfills in my application.

https://github.com/zloirock/core-js

After installing this, there are a few different ways to get it working.

If you use a polyfills entry point, add:

```
import "core-js/es6/reflect"
import "core-js/es7/reflect"
```

If you don't have a polyfills entry point you can use the webpack ProvidePlugin. Add this to your webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  ...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Reflect: 'core-js/es7/reflect'
  })
  ...
]
```

[where I got my answer](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/353#issuecomment-243324091)